# Who wins the game?

Tags: mathematics, nim

Two people play a game. The first one (A) picks one number from 1 to 10  and then the second one (B) also picks a number from 1 to 10 and adds it to the first  number; the next round continues in the same way.
Whoever gets to 45 is winner.

For example, A->4 and B->5 (4+5=9) A->3 (9+3=12) ... B->3(42+3=45) B is winner.

If A picks 3 in their first move, which number B can choose that definitely win the game for B?

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 9

Reasoning:

> B's goal is to be able to answer any A's move with a move which guarantees B the victory. If B's first move is 9, the current sum is 12, and the sum of numbers left to 45 is **33**, which is divisible by 11. After that whatever number *x* A picks, B answers with a number 11-*x* (which is always possible), increasing the current sum by 11 and reaching 45 on the fourth round.